# archetypal code from Ember's own site not working -- any ideas?

Tags: ember.js

There are several extensive code examples on a **[tutorial page](http://emberjs.com/guides/router_primer/#toc_fetching-data)**  at the ember web site that are all failing in a specific way.  As this is supposed to be archetypal ember code ostensibly to direct newcomers how to code in ember, I am at a loss.  Could someone who knows ember have a look at the code. (An example is directly above that bookmark I listed, and includes both the templates and js.

Specifically what's happening is that the main root page template has an outlet 'footer' that's only written to by the subpages, but when you navigate back to the home (root/index) page,  that outlet still has the info from the subpages showing, which it shouldn't.  The same thing is happening with the template called 'traversal' whose outlet is only written to by the subpages, but that outlet is also still showing info in it when you navigate back to the root.

I did run across a function `disconnectOutlet` in the API docs,  but it says you shouldn't hardly ever have to use it, and its not in the example code.  I tried it - evidently not actually in the api anymore.

If you want to run that code above you'll need the following from the ember site:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-1.0.pre.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, `disconnectOutlet` was added by this [pull request](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1277). You can use it to remove an outletView (by name) from a controller. For example, remove `myOutletViewName` from applicationController when exiting a certain route:

```
  aRoute: Ember.Route.extend({
    exit: function(router) {
      router.applicationController.disconnectOutlet('myOutletViewName')
    }
  })
```

Note that if you use `{{outlet}}` in your template, without specifying a name, the default name is `view` so you do:

```
router.applicationController.disconnectOutlet('view')
```

Comment: So, should those code examples have all been using disconnetOutlet.

Comment: Because what's its doing now is that the home page (when navigating back to it)  shows two complete copies of the links - one the home page itself generated in {body} the other copy just a relic created by a subpage in {footer} but still showing.